# Signup route with passport.js and dynamodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am currently trying to implement a simple signup process using passport.js. 
I am using the localStrategy in combination with a dynamodb for saving user credentials. Adding a new User to the database works fine, but for some reason the signup routes always returns with failureRedirect. I am new to node.js and passport.js so I might missunderstand a concept or something. So any help or direction pointing would be great.

Thanks :-)

**Signup Route**

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/index',
        failureRedirect : '/signup1', 
        failureFlash : true 
    }));
```

**Method for creating a new user**

```
 passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true 
    },



    function(req, email, password, done) {

        console.log('signup-route')
        process.nextTick(function() {

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to signup already exists
        User.readObject(email,function (err, user) {



          if (!(err instanceof errors.NotFoundError) && err){

            console.log(err)
            return done(err)
          } 

          // check to see if theres already a user with that email
            if (user) {
                console.log("taken")
                return done(null, false, req. flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } else {

               var data = {
                    email: email,
                    password : password
                }
                User.writeObject(null,data,function(err){
                  console.log(err);
                })
                console.log("write")
                //should trigger successRedirect
                return done(null, user)
            }

        })  

        });

    }));
```

Comment: Why you need passportjs to signup while you can directly create a user and use passportjs for only authentication?

Comment: After the signup I want to directly create a session for the user. So signup is just a way to authenticate for a user who has no credentials rightnow.

Comment: @Arif Khan forgot to tag you in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I  found the mistake. In the else branch I am returning `done(null, user)`.

This should be `done(null, data)` since there is no user object defined.

```
 // check to see if theres already a user with that email
            if (user) {
                console.log("taken")
                return done(null, false, req. flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } else {

               var data = {
                    email: email,
                    password : password
                }
                User.writeObject(null,data,function(err){
                  console.log(err);
                })
                console.log("write")
                //should be changed to done(null, data)
                return done(null, user)
            }
```